# SQL Server 2008R2 Linked Server to SQL Server 2000 showing incorrect server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, sql-server-2000

I have 2 servers and 4 instances

- Server 1 (SQL Server 2008R2) has instance a,b,c
- Server 2 (SQL Server 2000) has instance d

I created a linked server from server 1 instance c to server 2 instance d. When I expand the catalog for linked server I get server 1 instance b. Tried IP and DNS name no reason I can find anywhere for this to happen.

Any thoughts or ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Please show us the linked server configuration as well as a screen shot of what you are seeing.

Comment: May be an alias pointing to the wrong server ? Check that as well.